# location marker left right according to user movement in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on Google Maps in Android, I am updating location of user and drawing path on Maps. But I am having little problem in that I want to make the marker position to change according to user position.

For e.g if user takes left turn then Marker(i.e arrow (>)) position should also take left turn. This functionality is available in Google Maps. If anyone has any idea please kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the device's hardware to determine what direction the user is facing, and then draw your arrow accordingly.

[Here](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/03/create-our-android-compass.html) is a great tutorial on gathering the data to show a compass on screen (essentially what you want to do at the users location).

Comment: Great its what i am looking for. Thanks for your help. I will defiantly try this...

Comment: Yeah, But I have not yet tried it on real device as emulator does not support it. As soon as i try i will do update.

Comment: This is very useful...
 http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/08/simple-compass-sensormanager-and.html

Comment: Hey Austyn, I need a little help from you. I am done with the Compass functionality as well as I am done with drawing a updated direction path whenever user walk or drive. But as i have a drawable marker image like (>); i wish to update the image position like the compass. I know i have to used the draw method but I need some guidance that how can i achieve it. I am using ItemizedOverlay for updating the current marker position and drawing the route direction whenever its change. I have used LocationListener for that and onLocationChange method i am updating the route..

Comment: You should post this as a new question so everyone has a chance to answer it.